# Spread two-columned dataframe with duplicated rows into 3 cols

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, tidy

I have this kind of data frame in R

```
x       y
name1   value x
name1   value y
name2   value x
name2   value y
name3   value x
name3   value y
```

I want to convert it this way

```
x        y         z
name1   value x   value y
name2   value x   value y
name3   value x   value y
```

I've tried to reshape with `pivot_wider` but didn't work.

Comment: Get odd rows, and even rows, then cbind?

Comment: `"pivot_wider but didn't work."` Please provide the code as well, with error/warnings if any.

Comment: Yes. My actual table isn't that clean as in the question... 
So if I do df_wide <- df %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = x, names_from = y, values_from = y) 
The result is a table with 13 columns

Comment: is there not a way to split a table and put rows with even indexes (2-4-6-...) in column y and rows with odd indexes (1-3-5-...) in a new column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a `pivot_wider` option for you

```
df %>%
  arrange(x, y) %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(mn = c("y", "z")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = mn, values_from = y) %>%
  ungroup()
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  x     y       z      
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>
1 name1 value x value y
2 name2 value x value y
3 name3 value x value y
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
df <- read.table(text = "x       y
name1   'value x'
name1   'value y'
name2   'value x'
name2   'value y'
name3   'value x'
name3   'value y'", header = T)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(dummy = cumsum(x != lag(x, default = 'NULL'))) %>%
  mutate(dummy = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = x, names_from = dummy, values_from = y)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  x     `1`     `2`    
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>  
1 name1 value x value y
2 name2 value x value y
3 name3 value x value y
```

for odd rows/even rows segregation

```
df %>%
  mutate(dummy = (row_number() +1) %% 2) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = x, names_from = dummy, values_from = y)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  x     `0`     `1`    
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>  
1 name1 value x value y
2 name2 value x value y
3 name3 value x value y
```

OR

```
df %>%
  mutate(dummy = c('x_val', 'y_val')[1 +(row_number() +1) %% 2]) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = x, names_from = dummy, values_from = y)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  x     x_val   y_val  
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>  
1 name1 value x value y
2 name2 value x value y
3 name3 value x value y
```

Answer (score 0):

Get odd rows and even rows, then column bind:

```
cbind(df[c(TRUE, FALSE), ], z = df[c(FALSE, TRUE), 2])
#       x       y       z
# 1 name1 value x value y
# 3 name2 value x value y
# 5 name3 value x value y
```